# How to find out the concurrent users or connections on HAProxy server?

Tags: haproxy

I am using the HAProxy as a load-balancer and at the backend I have 4 web servers.
I am new to HAPrxoy and do not know how to find out the concurrent connections on HAProxy.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do this. First the stats socket, second the stats web end point. Setting up and using the stats web end point is easier in my opinion and more useful. To enable the stats end point add this to your haproxy config:

```
listen haproxy_stats :50000
stats enable
stats uri /
no log
```

This will enable the stats end point on the server port 50000
haproxyserver:50000

This will show a page with the current stats including concurrent connections. You can also look at the CSV version of the stats for scripting etc:
haproxyserver:50000/;csv

For more information:
haproxy 1.4 http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#stats%20enable
haproxy 1.5 http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#stats%20enable

Answer (score 1):

haproxy -vv will display the configuration settings for the haproxy instance maxconn=xxxx